# Gradle, define a collection of properties

Tags: android, gradle, collections

I'm working in a Gradle Script in order to deploy three Android environment automatically. 
The idea is define a group of properties whose will be used to hold all data from each environment. 
Example

```
[DEV, QA & Live]  {    
           buildFolder ="..."  
           envName     = "..." 
           excludeFiles=  "**/..." }
```

Then, for each operation copy code, edit files... I will only have to iterate each environment.

Basically, my problem is that I can't manage to find a way to create this collection.

Could someone explain the best way to hold  a group of properties?

```
I've already tried with:
project.ext.dev= {
 envName     = "live"
 buildFolder = "releaseLive"
 excludeFiles= ['**/..' ]
 }

project.ext.qa = {
 envName     = "live"
 buildFolder = "releaseLive"
 excludeFiles= ['**/..' ]
 }

project.ext.live = {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you want to do, but it sounds like you want to use a map. Remember Gradle scripts are just groovy.

so, something like:

```
project.ext.dev = [
  envName:"DEV",
  buildFolder: "releaseLive",
 ]

 project.ext.qa = [
  envName:"QA",
  buildFolder: "releaseLive",
 ]


task printProps << {
  println project.dev.envName
  println project.qa.envName
}
```

see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections

Comment: That was my idea, so my mistake was to use { instead of [. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What about to create 3 separate files with equal names (dev.properties, qa.properties and live.properties). And insert in them your properties

```
envName     = "live"
buildFolder = "releaseLive"
excludeFiles= ['**/..' ]
```

After that you can use this properties in your build.gradle config. Something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {...}

File propsFile = new File("dev.properties");
if (propsFile.exists()) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile));

    //after loading properties you can get values from them
    println properties['envName'];
    println properties['buildFolder'];
    println properties['excludeFiles'];
}
```

So to use value from some environment you will need to change file name. You can create an array of file names, and iterate them.

Comment: it could be a good idea too. I've been trying using a class class  `Environment{
    String type;
    String folderBuild;
    String[] notIncluded;
}`

Comment: and a list to hold all environments `List<Environment> environmentList = new ArrayList<Environment>();`   I wonder which one is more appropriate.

Comment: If you will keep this values in class, you should to initialize every of them and add every value manualy. If you will need more env values, you will need to  change you class signature, and add that values, again manualy. As for me better to keep in separate file, because in case of change values you should do less operations

Comment: You are right. The class solution is pointless because of the initialization, I pretty like your solution leaving the configuration in different files. Thanks.